# How the assembly version matching works exactly?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have assemblies in GAC with versions, 1.1.1.5, 1.1.5.1, 1.1.6.2, 1.2.1.1 and 2.1.2.1. My application have a reference of 1.1.3.0 version. Which assembly will be matched at runtime? and what are the actual rules for assembly matching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your reference requires a specific version, by default, it will fail on assembly load, as that version doesn't exist.

This can be configured, however, via [Assembly Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2.aspx).  There are various options of what will happen here, including:

- The reference can say that it doesn't care about versioning, in which case the newest is loaded.
- You can [configure your application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/433ysdt1.aspx) in a way that you specify how to redirect the binding.
- The assembly in the GAC can be [setup with a publisher policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz32563a.aspx) that specifies how to handle this.

Comment: Are you sure? because this documentation says, `Assemblies with the same name, major, and minor version numbers but different revisions are intended to be fully interchangeable` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx

Comment: @user960567 I've had binding/load errors with even just the build number mismatching.  That's the intention, but the policy files still need to exist.

Comment: @user960567 No - the documentation says "use this versioning scheme when you intend for this to match" - it doesn't say "the runtime will cause this to match" - that still requires a policy file.

Comment: where it says this and what settings says doesn't care about versioning?

Answer (score 5):

> Which assembly will be matched at runtime?

None will be matched, your program will bomb.

The documentation for the Version class talks *generically* about how you pick version numbers.  And yes, you normally consider a change in the build number to be a non-breaking change.  And a change in the revision to be low risk.  Things you consider when you pick an [AssemblyFileVersion].

However, the default CLR policy does *not* implement this kind of interpretation of the [AssemblyVersion], it insists on an **exact** match.  It is only happy when it find the exact same DLL that you compiled your program with.  This is not normally difficult to ensure.  You can override this policy and make it weaker, although you should always think twice about that.  There is a *very* long history of well intended minor changes in source code that just did not pan out that well in practice.  Something that Microsoft knows too well, having to maintain code that lasts for *decades*.  The default counter-measures against DLL Hell in the CLR are hard as a rock.  As they should be.  Ratcheting it down up to you.

Comment: Means documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx is wrong. I have tested this in framework 1.1, It picks the version with just matching major.minor. Is it changed in 4.0?

Comment: @user The documentation you linked to doesn't contradict this answer. The part you're reading is probably in the "Remarks" section, which talks about *conventions*. That's exactly what Hans says here in the middle paragraph. And just as some general advice, if you're interested in behavior in old frameworks like 1.1, that should be mentioned explicitly in your question. Answerers are going to tend to assume the current or current-1 version.